# node-celery vs node-amqp for RabbitMQ

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, celery

I've been recently reading into task queues and message queues, and I am a bit confused as to how everything fits together.

I see that both node-celery and node-amqp provide ways to add to the RabbitMQ queue. However, node-celery is described as a "task queue" while node-amqp is described as a "client for RabbitMQ". What is the difference? Or does node-amqp provide functionality similar to Celery already?

Also, doesn't RabbitMQ already have a queue? Why do I need Celery on top of RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two concepts here:

- RabbitMQ is message bus implementation that supports AMQP. So it is generic messaging system you can use for what ever you like (not just tasks).
- Celery is task management library/framework that uses AMQP (or database if you configure it to) to communicate between your code and worker processes. It handles task related responsibilities like fetching task-results, managing worker processes, etc.

Comment: so essentially, Celery can act as a client to an AMQP server suck as RabbitMQ?

Comment: Yeah, I guess you can say that.